# Resharper - how to disable indexing for the project in the solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, jetbrains-ide

The solution has a number of projects, among which one is auxiliary. It contains a hierarchy of classes, in which entries are stored localization constant. These files are large enough. 
The problem is that when I use navigation of ReSharper "**GoTo Everything/Type**": list is almost completely filled with the elements of this project. As a result, find the item you want is very difficult.

As I understand it, if ReSharper not will index the files, then, in principle, they will not display in ReSharper. **How to disable indexing ReSharper specific project in the solution?** But if there is another option: it would be great :)

I am using version  9.2 or 10, IDE VS2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Options, at *Search and Navigation* you can exclude certain items from the navigation. Adding the project folder to the exclusion list should work for you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! On 10 Resharper did not seem to have this option in the Search & Navigation, but in version 10.1 it is precisely there :) That solved my problem!